# CSS round corners issue with IE9

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I applied round corners style with my search box, but the thing is it's showing both normal style and with corners style in IE9 and while in IE10 it's not. Please have a look at snap shot of search box images from web and css style with HTML code.

[image: IE9]

[image: IE10]

code:

```css
.searchform {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; /* ie7 hack for display:inline-block */
    *display: inline;
    border: solid 1px #d2d2d2;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
    -moz-border-radius: 2em;
    border-radius: 2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    background: #f1f1f1;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#ededed));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ededed);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed'); /* ie7 */
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed'); /* ie8 */
}

.searchform .searchbutton {
        color: #fff;
        border: solid 1px #494949;
        font-size: 11px;
        height: 27px;
        width: 27px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
        -webkit-border-radius: 2em;
        -moz-border-radius: 2em;
        border-radius: 2em;
        background: #5f5f5f;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#9e9e9e), to(#454545));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #9e9e9e, #454545);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9e9e9e', endColorstr='#454545'); /* ie7 */
        -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#9e9e9e', endColorstr='#454545'); /* ie8 */
    }
```

```html
<div class="top-search">
                                                <div class="searchform" id="dvSearch" runat="server">
                                                    <table border="0">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <select id="searchSelect">
                                                                    <option selected="selected" value="">Select Type ...</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <input type="text" name="search" id="searchText" value="Enter Search Text"
                                                                    title="Enter Search Text"
                                                                    class="searchfield" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search...';}" onclick="clearThis(this)" />
                                                                <input class="searchbutton" type="button" value="Go" id="ancSearch" onclick="SearchFunction()" />
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

Thanks,
nag

Comment: Not happening to me but did you try `overflow: hidden;` ?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct Doctype and meta tags enabled? I believe they're needed for IE9 to render CSS3 properties.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```